# ASP.NET Repeater, Dynamically starting new table row

Tags: asp.net, repeater, newrow

I have the following repeater:

```
<table>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBrandRepeater">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkCompanyLink">
                            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgCompanyLogo" />
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

I want to start a new row every four table cells.

I don't want to used jQuery or Javascript to accomplish this.

The outputted html is supposed to look like this page:  http://rmtequipment.com/golfandturf.aspx

I have made an interface that will allow them to add these logos on their own.
So this page will be dynamically built.

What is the best way to accomplish this goal?

If a listview or gridview is a better approach I am open to that as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach in my opinion, is to use a [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) instead. You can control the `RepeatDirection` of the items as well as the # of columns via the `RepeatColumns` property and the layout to use via `RepeatLayout`.

So your DataList would be defined as:

```
<asp:DataList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatLayout="Table" ...
```

Comment: That sounds like a great Idea.  I will give it a try.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach would be to get rid of the table and use floated `div` elements since it is not a table nor contain tabular data.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBrandRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="logo">
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkCompanyLink">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgCompanyLogo" />
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </div>  
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then style up your div

```
div.logo{ float: left; width: 200px; display: inline; }
```

This will then natuarally break onto the next "line" based on the width of the element which is containing all these logos.

See this basic demo for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ygnEa/

Comment: I did consider this approach.  I just wanted something a little more constraining than floating.  If there was a way that I could add a div that clears the float after every fourth div I would have definitely used a css based layout.